# update function doesn't save the changes

Tags: angular, mongodb, service

i try to solve this problem for sometime, i would appreciate the help!

i try to build simple update function that its get at the first time the info from DB and then the user can change the current info to a new one.
i try to debug my code but i got to stage that i don't have any errors but still the new info that the user wrote doesn't change.

i tried to check my server with Postman, i check my requests and it work and i could change the info,i think the problem at my Client side.

here my code,

My Service:

```
//Update user:
updateUser(user: UserModel): void
{
  const index = this.users.findIndex((x) => x.id === user.id);
  if (index >= 0) {
    this.users[index] = user;
    this.http.put(`${environment.urlApi}/users/${user.id}`, user  ).subscribe(
      res => { console.log('user Updated!') }
    )}}
```

my function:

```
  updateVal(user) {  
    const updatedUser: UserModel = {
      id: this.userInput.id,
      name: user.fullName,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      address: {
        city: user.addressCity,
        street: user.addressStreet
      }
    };
    this.utils.updateUser(updatedUser) 
    console.log(updatedUser)  
  }
```

my HTML file:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm"  [style.border-color]=" isRed ? 'red' : 'green' " class="form-group" novalidate >
    <div class="card-body">
      <div>
        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Id: {{userInput.id}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullName">Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" formControlName="fullName"/>
        <div *ngIf="userForm.controls['fullName'].invalid && (userForm.controls['fullName'].dirty || userForm.controls['fullName'].touched)">
          <span *ngIf="userForm.controls['fullName'].errors.required">
            <i>Name is required</i>
          </span>
  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" formControlName="email"/>
        <div *ngIf="userForm.controls['email'].invalid && (userForm.controls['email'].dirty || userForm.controls['email'].touched)">
          <span *ngIf="userForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
            <i>Email is required</i>
          </span>
  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="details" formControlName="username" />
        <div *ngIf="userForm.controls['username'].invalid && (userForm.controls['username'].dirty || userForm.controls['username'].touched)">
          <span *ngIf="userForm.controls['username'].errors.required">
            <i>Username is required</i>
          </span>
  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="other-data">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (mouseover)="mouseOver=true" (click)="mouseOver=false">
        Other Data
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-3" [id]="mouseOver ? 'otherData' : 'other-id'" >
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngIf="mouseOver">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="addressCity">City:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addressCity" id="addressCity" formControlName="addressCity"  />
            <div *ngIf="userForm.controls['addressCity'].invalid && (userForm.controls['addressCity'].dirty || userForm.controls['addressCity'].touched)">
              <span *ngIf="userForm.controls['addressCity'].errors.required">
                <i>Address is required</i>
              </span>
      
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="addressStreet">Street:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addressStreet" id="addressStreet" formControlName="addressStreet"  />
            <div *ngIf="userForm.controls['addressStreet'].invalid && (userForm.controls['addressStreet'].dirty || userForm.controls['addressStreet'].touched)">
              <span *ngIf="userForm.controls['addressStreet'].errors.required">
                <i> Street is required</i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="updateButton">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="updateVal(userForm.value)" [disabled]="userForm.pristine || userForm.invalid">
          Update
        </button>
      </div>
```

thanks for your time!

Comment: Try with `let updatedUser: UserModel = {`

Comment: just try your offer but i get all the info undefined like that

Comment: Share your method: updateUser

Comment: The problem is most likely related to the use of Form Controls. I've written a series of articles on this concept.  https://dev.to/jwp/angular-form-validation-patterns-5c8b  FormControls in an of themselves are good, but difficult to work with.  I recommend getting rid of them and switching to just the ngModel binding. It uses formcontrolls internally and makes things much more simple.

Comment: thanks @JohnPeters i changed it to ngModel binding and its work now, also i read your guide, really helpful! thanks alot!